# Countif with Subtraction if column C has X as a value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a sheet that is a list of products available.

Column b is name and column "D" is blank unless shipped and then an "X" is put in that box

Then in columns "F" I have the values of column B using unique.

```
=sort(UNIQUE(B4:B100),1,True)
```

What I want is if an "X" is in column "D" then to subtract from the totals in column "G"

```
=COUNTIF($B$4:B100,G4)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BeuvT3ACYYpWWhrg7UKdQe2erY_P-czA73tV6qEBzdY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I know this is easy I am just not focused today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({INDEX(QUERY(B4:B, 
 "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B)''", 0),,1), 
 QUERY(IFERROR(QUERY(B4:B, 
 "select count(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B)''", 0)-
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(QUERY(B4:B, 
 "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B)''", 0),,1), QUERY(B4:D, 
 "select B,count(B) where D is not null group by B label count(B)''", 0), 2, 0))), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)})
```

[image: 0]